# Parable that describes why one wants to achieve Moksha?

Tags: moksha

In university my professor told a story or parable of why one would want to attain Moksha (and break the cycle of life and death).  The details are foggy but it generally involved a man with a wife and children that lived by the sea, and he asked an elder why he would want to achieve Moksha.  His wife and children were then killed by either a wave or a flood and the moral was that this was why, i.e. when one breaks the cycle of life and death and achieve Moksha they are one with everything and thus no longer have to deal with the grief of loving others only to lose them.

Has anyone ever heard such a parable or point to such a story online?

Comment: I don't know whether that parable is entirely correct. Because Maya (worldly bonds and all) is overcome by devotion to God; some saints even considered Moksha as **inferior** to Bhakti.

Comment: never heard or read of this parable

Comment: This sounds more like a tragedy rather than a parable. Sorry. As for 'why one wants to achieve Moksha'. The answer is this: 'Why one wants to be happy?'. Because Moksha is just a concocted name for Eternal Happiness. If someone has lived through enough experiences, then they will realize that happiness lies within, and this is what the Vedantic philosophers of India have described as 'Self Realization', i.e. realizing the spring of eternal happiness within you. All the best!

Comment: Thanks, it did sound tragic to me at the time as well...and maybe the prof made it up? to emphasize his point of how the cycle of rebirth does have its drawbacks